# Question on lattice paths

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Let $ P$ be a subset of $\mathbb{N}^2\setminus {(0,0)}$ with the two following conditions:

$(1) \quad $ every $x \in P$ has the form $(n,n)$, $(n+1,n)$ or $(n,n+1)$, and

$(2) \quad (n+1,n) \in P$ if and only if $(n,n+1) \in P$.

Let $P_m$ denote the set of paths from the origin to $(m,m)$ using steps from $P$, that consist of the single step (m,m) and also stay strictly below the diagonal ($y=x$) except at the origin and $(m,m)$.

I am some problem understanding how the elements of $P_m$ looks like. In particular, let us work with $P_3$. Let y be path from $(0,0) \rightarrow (2,1) \rightarrow (3,3)$. Is  $y \in P_3$ ? I would really appreciate it if some can please explain this to me. Example of an element in $P_3$ would be great or perhaps a general explanation.

Comment: If $\langle 2,1\rangle\in P$, then by $(2)$ we have $\langle 1,2\rangle\in P$ as well, and in that case $y\in P_3$. However, there are sets $P$ that satisfy $(1)$ and $(2)$ and do **not** contain $\langle 2,1\rangle$, and in those cases $y\notin P_3$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott   Could you provide please me an example of one element of $P_3$ ?

Comment: There are many subsets $P$ of $\Bbb N^2\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ that satisfy conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$; which paths are in $P_3$ depends entirely on which of these sets $P$ you’re using.

Comment: Got it. It makes sense to me now. Thanks :)